# How to calculate total harmonic distortion in PSpice?

Tags: oscillator, spice, pspice, hspice, total-harmonic-distortion

How can I calculate the total harmonic distortion of a sinusoidal Oscillator in Pspice?

I am using eldo and ezwave for the simulations and waveforms.

Comment: Run a harmonic analysis of the output waveform and note the significant harmonic amplitudes and do some math.

Comment: https://www.electro-tech-online.com/threads/thd-in-ltspice.153729/ https://www.diyaudio.com/forums/solid-state/177820-thd-ltspice.html https://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/ltspice-thd-measurement.153365/

Comment: In TRAN analysis you click "enable Fourier" and specify the fundamemtal frequency (1st harmonic). The programm calculated the THD factor (listed under "analysis" at the end of "examine output")